# changing ranking number to starts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ranking

I need to change my ranking number to a star
I used this following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/AhakQ/13/

but when ranking is zero - I see no stars at all
in this example when

```
$scope.ratings = [{
    current: 0,
    max: 10
}, {
    current: 3,
    max: 5
}];
```

How can I change it?

This is what I was trying to change

```
            var updateStars = function () {
                scope.stars = [];
                var isempty = 1;
                for (var i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
                    scope.stars.push({
                        filled: i < scope.ratingValue
                    });
                    isempty = 0;
                }
                if(isempty == 1)
                {
                   scope.stars.push({
                   rating: i < scope.ratingValue
                   });
                }
            };
```

Comment: Can you make a plunker or a jsfiddle with your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `$watch` you were having a condition `if(newVal)` which didn't let `0` go through creating stars in the first place. :)

Here's how it could have been:

```
scope.$watch('ratingValue', function (oldVal, newVal) {
    if (angular.isDefined(newVal)) {
        updateStars();
    }
});
```

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AhakQ/636/)